# How do I make a classwide CCArray with Cocos2d-x?

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x

I'm just starting to learn C++ and Cocos2d-x after a couple years of Objective-C.  Tonight's obstacle appears to be learning how to use the CCArray function as a classwide variable.

### HelloWorldScene.h

```
class HelloWorld : public cocos2d::CCLayer
{

public:
    // Here's a difference. Method 'init' in cocos2d-x returns bool, instead of returning 'id' in cocos2d-iphone
    virtual bool init();  

    // there's no 'id' in cpp, so we recommand to return the exactly class pointer
    static cocos2d::CCScene* scene();

    // a selector callback
    void menuCloseCallback(CCObject* pSender);

    // implement the "static node()" method manually
    CREATE_FUNC(HelloWorld);

    // static Array of tiles
    static cocos2d::CCArray* uniquetiles;
};
```

### HelloWorldScene.cpp

```
uniquetiles=CCArray::create();
uniquetiles->addObject(d00);
```

When I try to run the code, I get an error saying "undefined reference to 'Helloworld::uniquetiles'

What am I doing wrong here?  It seems like this should be straight forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add this variable in the class definition.

```
private:
    CCArray* uniquetiles;
```

Comment: Doh!  Can't believe I'm so blind.

Answer (score 0):

You are using static `CCArray` therefore you need to re-declare it in your CPP file:

```
cocos2d::CCArray* HelloWorld::uniquetiles;
```